# Want neural net example of rules {vector->string}

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am using data samples from a multispectral color sensor for color classification as an exercise in beginning to learn about neural networks.

I have succeeded with `Classify` for two data formats, `{list of 10 integers} -> "color-name"}` and `{list of 10 integers} -> integer}`.

I also succeeded with `NetChain` for the second, all integer, format.  However, I can't seem to get `NetChain` set up with `NetEncode` properly so that the color name gets changed to an integer.  `Classify` does this.  I would like to know how it is done.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26)

Comment: Can you add some sample data to help others solve your problem?

Comment: Here is a sample:  In[97]:= {spd2[[6000 ;; 6010, 1 ;; 2]]}

Out[97]= {{{146, 734, 659, 457, 5356, 770, 537, 973, 1321, 1956} -> 
   "Violet", {194, 418, 598, 722, 7470, 964, 1074, 2572, 3542, 
    2833} -> 
   "Orange", {195, 900, 1238, 1374, 7551, 938, 1558, 1557, 1820, 
    1875} -> 
   "Gray", {240, 321, 711, 1710, 9970, 1287, 2938, 3723, 4032, 
    2896} -> 
   "Yellow",..., {287, 604, 639, 581, 12897, 1109, 737, 2233, 7648, 
    6920} -> "Red"}}

Comment: Sorry about the formatting; I just copied and pasted from the notebook.  What format should I select from the Copy As menu to make it look nice in this forum?

Comment: Just FYI, the first eight numbers are from the visible spectrum, the ninth is a full intensity value, and the tenth is the near infrared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data={{146,734,659,457,5356,770,537,973,1321,1956}->"Violet",{194,418,598,722,7470,964,1074,2572,3542,2833}->"Orange",{195,900,1238,1374,7551,938,1558,1557,1820,1875}->"Gray",{240,321,711,1710,9970,1287,2938,3723,4032,2896}->"Yellow",{287,604,639,581,12897,1109,737,2233,7648,6920}->"Red"};
```

```
net = NetChain[
  {
   LinearLayer[20],
   LinearLayer[],
   SoftmaxLayer[]
   },
  "Input" -> Length@data[[1, 1]],
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", DeleteDuplicates@data[[;; , 2]]}]
  ]
```

[image]

```
netT = NetTrain[net, data[[;; , 1]] -> data[[;; , 2]]]
```

[image]

```
netT@data[[;; , 1]]
```

> {"Violet", "Orange", "Gray", "Yellow", "Red"}

Comment: Many thanks!  It works perfectly on the full data set.  I will now study your working example.  I have a lot to learn, but this has put me back on track.

Comment: @JohnDavis I was glad to help you.